# Replacing nvarchar(max) in Azure synapse table

Tags: string, azure, azure-synapse

While importing data from a csv file into synapse table, getting the following error:

*The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=String or binary data would be truncated.,Source=System.Data*

The source column datatype is nvarchar(max) & in synapse, nvarchar can't be set to max so I am using nvarchar(4000). However, even 4000 is not enough and I'm still getting this error. (As far as I know, this mismatch of character limitation is causing the issue?)

When specifying the datatype nvarchar(max) in synapse, I get the following error:
The statement failed. Column 'Preferences' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.

Any workaround for this issue, which is accepted in Synapse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default structure of a table in Azure synapse dedicated SQL pool is clustered column store, which does not support nvarchar(max). You can create the table as heap, and so use this data type.

```
  CREATE TABLE MyTable   
  (  
    mycolumnnn1 nvarchar(max),  
    mycolumn2 int )  
WITH ( HEAP )  
;
```

Please note that this may have performance affects, and also, generally , such large text fields do not fit well in a data warehouse.

Comment: Yes, I removed the clustered column store and used heap. It worked.