# Overflow error converting expression to data type NVARCHAR in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am encountering an error in my pipeline while loading data from a ServiceNow API into a table within a Synapse dedicated pool with nvarchar(max) columns.
The error message states:

`{"message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type NVARCHAR.`

Interestingly, the loading process works fine when I use `LEFT(description, 4000)` . However, I recognize that this is not the ideal solution, as it may lead to data loss.
And I've verified that the data type of the "description" column in the sink table is indeed nvarchar(max).

Could anyone provide guidance on a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, max length of characters for nvarchar data type in Synapse dedicated SQL Pool is 4000

[Data Types & Max length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits)
[image]

Here, you see the recommended data types
[Recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-data-types#minimize-row-length)

Workaround:
Create the table to use Heap and use nvarchar(MAX) as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517148/replacing-nvarcharmax-in-azure-synapse-table) post